# why this code run correctly? (python global keyword)

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, global

I'm a newbie... and studying about `global` keyword.
This code creates a random string.

I think *line 8*, `string.append(word[x])` make error on this code
because `string` is a global variable, so must be required `global` keyword. (global string)

But this code runs correctly...
Why can run correctly...?

```py
import random
word = 'a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z'.split(" ")
string = []
n = int(input())

def get(leng) :
    for i in range (0, leng) :
        x = random.randint(0, len(word)-1)
        string.append(word[x])
    sen = ''.join(string)
    return sen

print(get(n))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem to have any problems at first look, although not very clear on what you want to be happening or the error, but in `get()`, your list `string` doesn't need to be assigned as a global variable unless you want to re-define the variable. If for whatever reason, you decide to declare `string` or any variable in that matter inside a funcion, you would need to change its scope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) I know i don't need to be assigned as a global variable, but i wonder why I don't need to use global keyword on this code

Comment: It's because you're calling a method of list, not re-defining the variable.

Comment: oh you mean method is not a way to re-define the list... right? 

Comment: Exactly yes. All .append does is add a value at the end, not create a new one